# Java : Can we read with and without timeouts from a serial port using conditions ?

Tags: java, sockets, serial-communication, jssc

I am working on an Ingenico terminal for transaction processing. I use sockets and serial ports to communicate with the main server.

The socket and serial port communicate with each other, i.e., any data that is received on the serial port is immediately written onto the outputstream of the socket and any data that is received on the socket is written to the serial port.

There is a sequence of this dialogue that takes place: 
eg: when the socket sends a message to the serial port, the serial port responds with an ACK within a certain number of milliseconds and then the serial port sends another message to the socket and vice versa.

I need to have a timeout mechanism that checks if i n=receive an ACK within a certain time limit (a few milliseconds). I have used Timer and TimerTask in order to do this. And i have a conditional read from the serial port in order to do this. My question is if this will work? Am I on the right track?

Code so far:

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
{
    byte[] BytesFromSerialPort = null;
    //timeout of 500ms to get either an ACK or NAK from the serial port or the socket on port 6000
    int timeout = 10;

    if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0)
    {
        BytesFromSerialPort = new byte[event.getEventValue()];
        try
        {
            if(IsAckExpected)
                BytesFromSerialPort = serialPort.readBytes(event.getEventValue(), 1000*timeout);
            else
                BytesFromSerialPort = serialPort.readBytes(event.getEventValue());

            //print statements
            System.out.printf("SERIAL RX %04d: ", event.getEventValue());
            for(byte b : BytesFromSerialPort)
                System.out.printf("%c", (char)b);
            System.out.println();
}
}
```

The condition: If the next message expected is an ACK then I set a timeout on it.

Comment: You don't need a `Timer` or a `TimerTask` when you already have a read-with-timeout mechanism that you are already using. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I need to set a timeout only when the socket is about to receive an ACK from the serial port and vice versa. I do not need a timeout mechanism when the socket and the serial port are communication using other messages. Using JSSC's timeout mechanism will impose a timeout on all the reads, which I do not want.

Comment: I get it. I do not need a timer task. But will the following piece of code work?  Can we set different timeouts for socket reads based on conditions?

Comment: if(condition1)                                                                                                                                                                                           socket.setSoTimeout(timeout1);                                                                        else if(condition2)                                                                            socket.setSoTimeout(timeout2);

Answer (score -1):

Basically what you are trying to do in known as com port redirection. First you non-blocking read/write to make sure application never stuck in serial operations. Second consider using Thread.sleep coupled with number of retries to make algorithm more stronger.

Try serial communication manager library for serial port communication in java. See implementation of xmodem in their source code at github as it contains both timeout and ACK based read/write.

Further their are com port redirection drivers that do exactly what you are trying to do. If your project permits consider them. See also port servers which does exactly same as you need. You need to add security also if you will use simple socket for TCP/IP.